# PyPDF2: PdfFileMerger merges file multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf

I try to merge one pdf file to a couple others but while it handles the first few files just fine it somehow merges the file again after the 5.
To clearify:
- i have 12 pdf files, all of them have 1 one page
- i want to merge or add a pdf file to each of the above files (can have multiple pages)

what happens?
the first 4 pdfs get merged the way i want, the 5.-7. get the file i want to add 2 times, 8.-10. 3 times and 11.-12. 4 times.

i tried to use open(pdf) and close it after and also to close the merger inside the loop but it didnt helped

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader
import os

pdfs = [a for a in os.listdir() if a.endswith(".pdf")]
appendfile = input("PDF to append: ")

if appendfile in pdfs:
    pdfs.remove(appendfile)

x = 1
for pdf in pdfs:
    print("working on " + pdf)
    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    merger.append(PdfFileReader(pdf, 'rb'))
    merger.append(PdfFileReader(appendfile, 'rb'))
    merger.write(str(x)+".pdf")
    x += 1
merger.close()
```

in this case the resulting files (12) should all have 3 pages, one from them selfe and 2 added by the appendfile

Comment: Indent `merger.close()` into the for-loop, closing it every time.

Comment: @Joe like already mentioned, i did that and it didnt helped, also the merger will be newly created every time

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with your file list. Try without.